# How to run a javascript file with node.js

Tags: node.js

I have just started learning node.js and i am trying to open a local .js file. The file is stored on desktop and its location is something like `C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\hello.js`.

I use the following command:

`node C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\hello.js`

Now i use this command but all i get is `...` and nothing happens. I have installed node.js and use its own terminal. Other commands also work well without any problem but i am stuck at this very beginning step.

Comment: You are trying to open a file or run the file ?

Comment: @swapnesh i am trying to run the file of course.

Comment: what you have in your file ? and what you want to output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a cmd file in nodjs-folder. The cmd-file has only one line:

> node %1

Then I told windows to always open js files with this cmd file.